# Connect Android device to Wifi for internet and ethernet simultaneously

Tags: wi-fi, networking, lan

I have a Samsung tablet where I want to use wifi for internet connection and ethernet to communicate to other network devices connected to it such as Field Bus Coupler etc simultaneously.
Right now once I connected LAN with android device it disconnected from wifi.

Comment: It simply disconnects. Without root is there any possibility?

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Comment: I am working on a solution in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499840/android-9-ethernet-and-wifi-simulataneously I hope this is still relevant to you... did you find a solution yet?